# Import module missing when running python script from SSH

Tags: python, linux, ssh, module

I have a peculiar scenario where I have to run a remote script in server B from my linux client 'C'. Catch is that I can reach server B only through server A (as B is in an isolated network reachable only through a DMZ server 'A').

Currently when I run the following command it seems to work perfectly fine:

```
C-SERVER-PROMPT# ssh user@A ssh user@B hostname
```

Here I get server 'B's name as output as expected. However, when I try to run a python script on server 'B', it **fails with error stating that it cannot find modules to import**.

Is ther a way to pass location of module-location when executing python script remotely using SSH ?

Comment: I don't think the network route to B is relevant, unless B's Python installation is actually storing its files on a networked drive.  You will need to install any modules you need on B.

Comment: Let us assume that B already has all modules installed.

Comment: Then it should already be working.  Can you give an example of a script that fails, along with a complete error message?

Comment: I get the following error: 


 994     import gflags                                                               
 995 ImportError: No module named gflags

Comment: Is the `gflags` module installed on server B?  If you get into a shell on server B and do `python -c "import gflags"` at the shell prompt, do you get an error?

Comment: I have found the same problem - did you ever find a solution?